# Dapper DynamicParameters returning error

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

I am currently using the latest version of dapper, version 1.50.0-beta9. The provider I am using for Oracle is the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, version 12.1.2400.
I am getting an error when using dapper's dynamic parameters. My code is similar to the example below:

```
public class PersonDAL : OracleBase {

    public PersonDAL() : base() {
    }

    public PersonDAL(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {
    }

    public const string ParamPersonID = ":personid";
    public const string ParamClassID = ":classid";
    private const string getPersonByClassAndID = "SELECT PERSON_ID AS PersonID, PERSON_DESCRIPTION AS PersonDescription, CLASS_ID AS ClassID FROM TABLE_PERSON WHERE PERSON_ID = " + ParamPersonID + " AND CLASS_ID = " + ParamClassID;

    public SystemModel GetModelByPersonID_ClassID(int classID, int personid) {
        DynamicParameter = new DynamicParameters();
        DynamicParameter.Add(ParamClassID, classID);
        DynamicParameter.Add(ParamPersonID, personid);
        return Connection.QuerySingle<SystemModel>(getPersonByClassAndID, DynamicParameter);
    }
}
```

This is returning this error:

> Invalid parameter binding
>   Parameter name: personidAND

Comment: The above solution now works

Answer (score 0):

You are missing syntax in the SQL. What you have is

```
WHERE Foo=:fooBar=:bar
```

You need a `AND` or `OR` and some spaces in the middle.

You don't actually need `DynamicParameters` in this scenario, btw. The "classic" dapper usage here would be just:

```
new { classID, personID }
```

as the parameters object.

Comment: Yeah, just saw I forgot to put an AND on the query. either way though when I have an AND on the query I get: Invalid parameter binding
Parameter name: personidAND.... So you are saying I must try change the return to:  return Connection.QuerySingle<SystemModel>(getSystemBySystemCode,new {classID, personID});

Comment: OK, just your suggestion and I am still getting the same issue Invalid parameter binding
Parameter name: personidAND

Comment: Ok fixed it thanks, downloaded dapper and debugged it

Comment: @BananaGuard and what was the final problem? Because so far, all I'm seeing is malformed SQL...